# Ao consumir uma API que me retorna dados serializados em JSON, como eu faço para saber os tipos de dados das propriedades?

Tags: c#, json, web-service, api

Não tenho experiência com JSON e nem com consumo de web services, mas estou tentando consumir uma API que me retorna dados meteorológicos.

[Aqui está a documentação](http://openweathermap.org/current) da API que estou tentando consumir.

Essa API me retorna dados serializados em JSON. Pelo que li sobre JSON, a melhor maneira de acessar esses dados após realizar o download deles seria realizar a de-serialização dos mesmos em um objeto de uma classe com propriedades idênticas as propriedades do objeto retornado pelo web service.

É isso mesmo?

Mas como eu sei com precisão os tipos das propriedades dos objetos que estou recebendo em JSON?

Na API que eu mencionei eu encontrei um exemplo de resposta, esse aqui:

```
{"coord":
{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"cmc stations",
"main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
"clouds":{"all":75},
"rain":{"3h":3},
"dt":1435658272,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
"id":2172797,
"name":"Cairns",
"cod":200}
```

O que eu fiz foi copiar esse modelo, e colar no Visual Studio usando a opção Paste Special > Paste as JSON classes, o que me gerou estas classes:

```
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Coord coord { get; set; }
            public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
            public string _base { get; set; }
            public Main main { get; set; }
            public Wind wind { get; set; }
            public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
            public Rain rain { get; set; }
            public int dt { get; set; }
            public Sys sys { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int cod { get; set; }
        }

        public class Coord
        {
            public float lon { get; set; }
            public float lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class Main
        {
            public float temp { get; set; }
            public int pressure { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
            public float temp_min { get; set; }
            public float temp_max { get; set; }
        }

        public class Wind
        {
            public float speed { get; set; }
            public int deg { get; set; }
        }

        public class Clouds
        {
            public int all { get; set; }
        }

        public class Rain
        {
            public int _3h { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sys
        {
            public int type { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public float message { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public int sunrise { get; set; }
            public int sunset { get; set; }
        }

        public class Weather
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }
```

O problema aqui é que quando eu faço o download do JSON via HttpClient, ao tentar de-serializar o mesmo, eu obtenho alguns erros de tipos, como por exemplo a tentativa de armazenar dados de ponto flutuante em propriedades de tipo float. Meu código:

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync("weather?q=London,uk&appid=010101010101010101101");
Rootobject currentWeather = new Rootobject();
currentWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
MessageBox.Show(currentWeather.name);
```

Eu entendo que nesse caso eu poderia simplesmente ir alterando os tipos de dados nas propriedades das classes que criei. Minha dúvida é, estou fazendo esse procedimento da maneira correta? Está faltando alguma coisa na documentação da API oficial, onde deveriam informar os tipos de dados?

Esse tipo de implementação na tentativa e erro, realizando testes e descobrindo os tipos das propriedades com certeza não deve estar certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim a forma como esta a usar actualmente é correcta e tem o problema por si apontado. Se o tipo da propriedade no servidor for alterada tem que alterar a propriedade do seu modelo para o tipo certo. Há uma forma de evitar isso usando o `dynamic` que esta disponível a partir de `C# 4.0`

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter(); 
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, converter); 
//agora pode aceder as propriedades de obj 
var propriedade = obj.coord.lon
```

é de notar que esta abordagem tem tipificação dinâmica (isto quer dizer que não tem auxilio do compilador para verificar as propriedades existentes etc.) e normalmente não é encorajada por este mesmo motivo.

Lembrei-me agora que uma alternativa melhor pode ser tornar as suas propriedades `Nullable`. Por exemplo em vez de usar `int` usar `int?`, em vez de `float` usar `float?` e por ai fora. Dessa forma se a propriedade nao existir ela toma o valor null e a deserializacao funciona sem problemas.